# Clicking on any radio button in my created list results in only the first <select> field being activated

Tags: javascript, php

Here is the video in specific from what i mean. It is hosted on my personal drive
[video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UIwCLqnhOz5ZyHY9UrChm9E42bB1cENT)

Here is my code

```html
<?php
$pagetitle="Search Report";
include "includes/header.php";
include("config.php");
include("connection.php");
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
$name=$_GET['filo'];
$ksm=$_GET['kisim'];
$drs=$_GET['hders'];
$ndrs=$_GET['dname'];
$tch=$_GET['tname'];

?>

<script>
//Here Is javascript code
function enable() {
   document.getElementById('option').disabled=false;

}
</script>


<style type="text/css">
  input[type="radio"]{
    margin: 0px 4px 0px;
  }
</style>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
                    <div class="templatemo-line-header" style="margin-top: 0px;" >
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <hr class="team_hr team_hr_left hr_gray"/><span class="span_blog txt_darkgrey txt_orange">  </span>
                            <hr class="team_hr team_hr_right hr_gray" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
 <div class="table-responsive">
                 <table class="ui celled table table table-hover">
                  <form action="check.php" method="get">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Adı ve Soyadı</th>
                      <th>Dersin Adı</th>
                      <th>Dersin Saatı</th>
                      <th>Öğretim Elemanı</th>
                      <th>Durum</th>
                      <th>Sebepi</th>
                      <th>ID</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
     <tbody>
          <?php
  $query3=mysqli_query($connect,"select * from student where filo='$name' and kisim='$ksm' ORDER BY  student_name");
$arra=-1;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($query3))
{

$arra++;
?>

  <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row[1] ?></td>
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row[1] ?>" name="std_name[]">
      <td><?php echo $ndrs ?></td>
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ndrs ?>" name="ndrs[]">
      <td><?php echo $drs ?></td>
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $drs?>" name="drs[]">
      <td><?php echo $tch ?></td>
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $tch ?>" name="tch[]">          
      <td>
///////HERE IS ONE PART OF THE CODE
      <input  type="radio"  name="attendance[<?php echo "$arra" ?>]" value="Mevcut" checked="checked" >Mevcut
      <input  type="radio"  name="attendance[<?php echo "$arra" ?>]" onclick="enable()" value="Gayri">Gayrı
      </td>
      <td>

      <select class="form-control" id="option" name="option[<?php echo "$arra" ?>]" disabled  >
      <option selected value="Mevcut">Mevcut</option>
      <option value="Vizite">Vizite</option>
      <option value="Hst Muayene">Hst Muayene</option>
      <option value="Izinli">Izinli</option>
    </select>
      </td>
      <td><?php echo $row[0] ?>
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row[0] ?>" name="id[]">
      </td>

</tr>

<?php } ?>

       </tbody>



            </table>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" name="submit2">Gönder</button>
            </form>
            </div><!--table-responsive-->

            </div><!--row-->
            </div><!--container-->
            <?php include "includes/footer.php"; ?>
```

I try to explain my problem.
Scenario is like that. Some infos are taken from a submit form and with this infos i create a list then created list has 2 radio buttons and by default a disabled select area.
The problem is here. When i click on "Gayri" button  field must be activated for every person in that list instead of that just the first field is activated.

Can anyone help me? I want for every possible person in the list when i click on "gayri" radio button the  field to be activated.

Comment: Your select drop down is not disabled by default, you have a quoting issue, and what needs to be activated when Gayri radio button is selected?

Comment: Exactly that Andrew Lohr.